# SSIS prevent the insert of data rows from flat file that already exist in the SQL Server table

Tags: ssis

‌I‌‌ need to create a SSIS package in which I am reading a flat file (provided monthly with many defined columns)  and writing the data to a already defined SQL Server table (with lot of data already in SQL table). In the SQL table design view, I have datatypes including float ,datetime , bigint, varchar (which are already defined and CANNOT be changed)

I need to prevent the insert of any data rows from flat file that already exist in the SQL Server table.‌ How can I achieve this ?

I‌ tried to achieve this using lookup transformation ‌‌‌but in Edit mappings I get an error while creating relationships "Cannot map the lookup column because the column is set to a floating point data type" . I am able to create the relationships for all other data types but then there are some data rows in source file which differ from data in sql table in floating point values only and the expectation is that these rows will be inserted.

‌ Is there any other simple way to achieve this ?

T‌hanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to convert the columns which has problem in mapping using data conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

neither SSIS nor SQL bulk load (the SQL feature that is behind the SSIS load task) permit this out of the box.

you can use the method described by @sasi, and in your lookup, define the sql query yourself with sql cast (the convert keyword). But even if you could solve your cast issue this way, you will surely face a performance problem if you load a large amount of data.

There are two way to deal with it:

The first (the easiest but quiet slow compared to the other option, maybe even more slow than your solution in some conditions), use an insert statement command using sql command for each row like the following:

```
INSERT target_table (val1, val2, id)  
SELECT $myVal1, $myVal2, $myCandidateKey
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM target_table as t WHERE t.id = $myCandidateKey);
```

The second implies the creation of a staging table on the target database. This table has the same structure than your target table. It is created once for good. You must also create an index on what is supposed to be the key that will define if the record might already be loaded. Your process will empty it prior any execution for an obvious purpose. Instead of loading the target table with SSIS, you load this staging table. Once this staging table is loaded, you will run the following command just once:

```
INSERT target_table (val1, val2, id)  
SELECT stg.val1, stg.val2, stg.id
FROM staging_target_table as stg
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM target_table as t WHERE t.id = stg.id);
```

This is extremely fast, compared to the first solution.

in this case, I supposed that what permits you to recognize you row is a key (the "id" column), but if you actually want to compare the full row, you will have to add the comparison like this for the first solution:

```
INSERT target_table (val1, val2)  
SELECT $myVal1, $myVal2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM target_table as t WHERE t.val1 = $myVal1 and t.val2 = $myVal2);
```

or like this for the second solution:

```
INSERT target_table (val1, val2, id)  
SELECT stg.val1, stg.val2, stg.id
FROM staging_target_table as stg
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM target_table as t WHERE t.val1 = stg.val1 and t.val2 = stg.val2);
```